# Is there a way to report Twitter spam?

Tags: twitter, spam-prevention

I just found some Twitter spam. How can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go to the profile of the account sending the tweets there's a drop down (the gear). The bottom option of that is to report the account for spam.

[image]

Having reported the account you can then block that account so you'll no longer see the spam posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also DM the @spam account. Of course this doesn't actually block them, but it alerts the authorities